# How Do I PHP Echo Content From My Database?

Tags: php, mysqli, opencart

I am trying to securely echo out content that exists within my opencart database.

The table is called **oc_category_description** and the row content I want to echo is within a row called **seo_h2**

My goal is to echo the content within between opening / closing H2 tags on my TPL file.

This works for the row "name"

```
<?php echo $category['name']; ?>
```

But this it doesn't work

```
<?php echo $category['seo_h2']; ?>`
```

How do I safely do this? I am using mysqli, OpenCart 2.3

Comment: What did you try ???

Comment: '<?php echo $category['name']; ?>' works for the row "name" but when I try '<?php echo $category['seo_h2']; ?>' it doesnt work

Comment: `var_dump($category)` it will give you complete detail of $category and its contents

Comment: Can you post your code ?? what you have tried so far???

Comment: first print your row and add  what you have tried so far?? let me know about what is your output??

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php print_r($category); ?>`
```

it will give you the result of complete row.

further you can work with loop for fetching the whole row like below:

```
foreach($category as $cat){
  echo $cat;
  }
```

keep coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$a = '<h2>demo example</h2>';
echo preg_replace("/<.*?>/", " ", $a);
```

Comment: Best practice to never [regex x/html](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1422451).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get multidimensional Array data then you should get multidimensional array for **$categories**

```
$categories = /*your multidimensional array*/
foreach ($categories as $category){
   echo $category["name"];
   echo $category["seo_h2"];
}
```

I thinks this works for you

Answer (score 0):

That's more complex than your description.
OpenCart uses MVC 
Model: catalog/model/catalog/category.php
(function getCategory)
passing the information to Controller: catalog/controller/product/category.php

Which you need to add the following to this file: catalog/controller/product/category.php

Find this line:

> $data['description'] =
>   html_entity_decode($category_info['description'], ENT_QUOTES,
>   'UTF-8');

and add this after:

> $data['seo_h2'] = $category_info['seo_h2'];

Now in the view file (category.tpl) you can write this:

```
<?php echo $category['seo_h2']; ?>
```